# SAS When the code below is executed, how many columns will be in the Willis dataset?

Tags: sas

When the code below is executed, how many columns will be in the Willis dataset?

```
data Willis;
  put "Willis"; /* Line 32 */
  do b = 1 to 12;
    A = rand("normal", 12.5, 1.57); /* Line 34 */
           do j = 1 to 5;
      lev = rand("normal", 4, 2.155) + A; /* Line 36 */
      output;
    end;
  end;
  put "Willis" b=; /* Line 40 */
run;
```

Comment: What is your answer? Why?

Comment: 60. B goes from 1 to 12. J from 1 to 5. 12*5=60. only `output` prints to file in this sort of datastep. Homework?

Comment: 60 is correct for the number of rows.

Answer (score 1):

A data step that does not use a statement `keep` or `drop` or data set option `keep=` or `drop=` will output every non-automatic variable in the program data vector (pdv).  When looking at the code observe statements that involve a variable, those variables will be part of the pdv.

The four non-automatic variables are:

- `b` - first used in `do` loop statement
- `A` - first used to receive a random value
- `j` - first used in `do` loop statement
- `lev` - first used to receive a random value